# Diffuse indirect pass shows part of texture

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-passes

Trying to save "DiffInd" pass of composition layer render pass as image. But I see part of the object texture being rendered.

Attached is the texture image and Render pass composition shader.
[image: Render Layers in composition]

[image: Rendered DiffInd]

[image: Texture used for cube]

[image: Shader setup]

Comment: Did you use the texture itself as base color of the object or is it used as a mix factor for colors and/or metallic or something similar? Would have been nice if you showed us the material setup of the seemingly incorrect appearing object. Because, if the texture for example is used to make the text metallic, than (all) the diffuse passes would show this part as black. And of course if the black part has the shape of the text, this part of the texture becomes somehow visible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann added texture and shader details

Comment: As it seems (what I did not really know since I usually never use the _DiffInd_ output) it is simply because the color in those areas is pure black (0, 0, 0) hence the _DiffInd_ (and the _DiffDir_) pass just shows that these parts do not contribute to the diffuse lighting at all. If you make the black text just very dark grey, it starts vanishing (especially if you would denoise the pass). Maybe when the question will be re-opened I can write a proper answer with screenshots.

Comment: But it is not just the black text. Even if you would just take the colors without any text, you could see differences between the colored areas. On the cube where each side has its own color and is facing in a different direction it's not visible, but if you just take a flat plane and put the texture on it (even if you paint the text out), you can see differences between the colored parts themselves and the white background as well. With a _Denoise_ filter it might be smoothed to look the same, but not if you plug _Denoising Normal_ and (especially) _Denoising Albedo_ in there.

Comment: The more I think about it, is there a reason why you think different colored (or different bright) parts of surfaces should all reflect light the same in the diffuse passes? It is not just textures, just using different base colors in the _Principled BSDF_ would show the same effect.