# DiffInd RenderLayer pass shows part of texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

Trying to save "DiffInd" pass of composition layer render pass as image. But I see part of the object texture being rendered.

Attached is the texture image and Render pass composition shader

[image: Composition layer and Shader]
[image: Render Pass Output]
[image: Cube Texture]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "DiffInd"

Comment: this diffuse indirect pass in the composition renderlayer pass node. I have attached images

Comment: You have already asked this question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300028/diffuse-indirect-pass-shows-part-of-texture. Please edit/improve that post to draw more attention instead of duplicating it.

Comment: 1. You asked this before as @taiyo pointed out and 2. I gave you an explanation in the comments there and 3. as I also mention there, why should different colors/brightnesses not show up in the _DiffInd_ pass?

Comment: Hello, @user170883, please edit the original (re-opened) rather than post a duplicate. Thanks.